# I‘m stuck in how to represent the formula of ant-colony-algorithm in latex

Tags: algorithms

I try to use the latex code to represent the following formula, but failed. How to fix it?
[image]

```
\begin{equation}
p^k_{ij} = \frac {\tau^\alpha_{ij}+\eta^\beta_{ij}} \sum_{\substack{j \in \Lambda}} \tau^\alpha_{ij}+\eta^\beta_{ij}\,
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Enclose the denominator within a pair of braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reproduces it, I think. It comes in two variations, with `\alpha` and `\beta` above the indices or shifted to the right. Use `\limits` instead of `\substack` for the `\sum`. (It is a bit surprising the left-hand side has a `k` superscript an the right-hand side `\alpha` and `\beta` but I just do not know the background.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
p^k_{ij} = \frac{\tau_{ij}{}^\alpha+\eta_{ij}{}^\beta}
{\sum\limits_{j \in \Lambda} \tau_{ij}{}^\alpha+\eta_{ij}{}^\beta}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
p^k_{ij} = \frac{\tau_{ij}^\alpha+\eta_{ij}^\beta}
{\sum\limits_{j \in \Lambda} \tau_{ij}^\alpha+\eta_{ij}^\beta}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You missed the second `{}` in the `\frac{}{}`command. Keep the syntax in mind.

```
p^k_{ij} = \frac {\tau^\alpha_{ij}+\eta^\beta_{ij}} \sum_{\substack{j \in \Lambda}} \tau^\alpha_{ij}+\eta^\beta_{ij}\,
```